# Is this integral automatically zero?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

If I integrate $\int e^{iz}\,dz$ for z complex, along the positive real line, 
then is the imaginary part of the integral $i\int \sin(x)\,dx$ automatically equal to zero (integration only along the real line)?

I know that integrating a real function over a real interval can only ever result in a real number answer, but in this case, the integrand is a complex number -- Euler's formula.  So, I am a little confused.

However, I have a feeling that the imaginary part of the integral must be zero, a proof that I am working on depends on this to happen.  So, I just wanted to confirm.

Thanks

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix}\,dx $ has no limit.  And its imaginary part is not zero unless the integral is interpreted as a Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: @Dr.MV, what if we were allowed to assume that this integrand, coupled with another factor or two, with constants or integration variables, helps make the integral converge over the positive half line?  Is the imaginary part of this integral then automatically zero?  Thanks,

Comment: Not in general.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks @Dr.MV`, I'll revise my proof...

Comment: I finally got it @Dr.Mv -- it took a somewhat tricky substitution and moving some terms around, then equating the real parts, and also getting a bonus equation for the imaginary parts.  Thanks so much,

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.